# How to loop a bunch of div with different ids?

Tags: html, razor

I am curious how to create like 5 divs and each id is different like this by loop them inside of manually typing them all out.

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<div id="div5"></div>
```

I would assume you would create a for loop but I dont know what to put in the html to put the counter in the id name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use a `for` loop:

```
@for(var i = 1; i < 6;i++){
    <div id="@("div" + i)"></div>
}
```

Amended to take account of "div" prefix in the id.

Comment: Just for general knowledge. why to use with `var` and not `int`?

Comment: This will set the ids as: id="1", id="2", etc... don't forget to add "div" in the id.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Well spotted. Amended accordingly.

Comment: @Dvir You can use `int` instead, but for local variables like that where the type is clear, I tend to use `var`.

Comment: @MikeBrind But why? is it more efficient?

Comment: @Dvir No, there is no difference in efficiency. It is just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know where in the overall HTML file you want those div elements to be placed, before worrying about the code that automatically would put them there.  If you just want to append them, you can use the document.write() function.  If you want them to be inside some other element, such as a form element, then things get a bit trickier.

Here is some JavaScript code showing several possibilities (the JavaScript would be called by an "onload" event handler for the body element of the document):

```
var frm, dv, indx, str, txt;
frm = document.getElementById("FormId"); //obviously the form element needs an id
for(indx=1; indx<6; indx++)
{ str = "div" + indx;
  dv = document.createElement("div");
  dv.id = str;
//If the div should contain some text, then you also need lines like these two:
  txt = document.createTextNode("Here is some text for " + str);
  dv.appendChild(txt);

  frm.appendChild(dv); //ok, now insert the div into the form
//Another alternative involves yet another function:
  document.body.insertBefore(dv, frm); //PRECEDE the form element with the div
//Finally, as originally mentioned:
  document.write(dv); //append the div at the end of the document
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or in php:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) { 
     print("<div id='div$i'> </div>"); 
}
```

Comment: I assumed, since the question is tagged Razor, that the OP would like an example using Razor syntax.